# What does the ptr operator do as part of operand to lea

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, disassembly

I met this piece of disassembly that I am unsure about what it does

```
lea rsi, ptr [rip+0x26b0f]
```

I know that the **ptr operator** together with size such as "dword ptr [...adress]" will dereference the value at the address.
Example 1:

```
 mov eax, dword ptr [rip+0x26b0f]
```

We are copying the value at address [rip+0x26b0f] into eax.

Also the form I know for lea (load effective address).

Example 2:

```
lea rsi, [rip+0x26b0f]
```

This last one would calculate the address expression and place the address in rsi (not the value at the address).

So what is the original assembly code supposed to do? Just calculate the address like example 2 and store it into rsi, or calculate the address AND dereference?

Comment: PTR does the same thing it always does in terms of MASM syntax; it's redundant in this case because there's a register inside square brackets which already means memory operand.  LEA puts the effective address in a register, instead of using it to accesses memory like other instructions would.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks! edited with mov. I thought it might be redundant but wasn't sure if there weren't some mechanic to dereference a double-pointer.

Comment: Nope; when you're wondering something like that, just check with a disassembler to see if you get the same machine code for both ways.  (And check Intel's manuals for addressing modes and/or for `lea`: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea).  Remember, the CPU runs machine code, not asm source, so all that matters is the machine code your assembler emits for different syntax.  If the machine code is the same, there is no difference.

Comment: I am unsure what do you mean by "just check with a disassembler to see if you get the same machine code for both ways." I assume I can write high-level language code that I think will disassemble to the "correct assembly" for both versions and compare the opcodes?

Comment: MASM converts this asm source code into bytes of machine code, like `48 8d 35 0f 6b 02 00` for  `lea  rsi,[rip+0x26b0f]`.  (I actually assembled that with the GNU assembler, and disassembled with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`, because my desktop is Linux, not Windows.  But same idea.)

Comment: Use a disassembler that includes a hex dump of the machine code, and also look at what instruction it disassembles back into.  Assemble + disassemble is sort of a way to canonicalize your asm source, if you pick a disassembler that uses nice syntax. e.g. https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv has a MASM output mode.  Hopefully the debugger built-in to Visual Studio also has a disassembly mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks a lot for the real work, I have exactly the same machine code bytes. I am using the dlv debugger for go (disass command from thecli) to get at the disassembly I originally gave as example. My assembly development environment is a bit rusty, so couldn't quickly did the test you did - Many thanks!